# Trying to generate a 128 x 128px square in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing it from a tutorial. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = (128,128)
image = np.zeros(size).astype(np.uint8)
image[1:64,1:64] = 255
image
np.array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
          [  0, 255, 255, ...,  0,  0,  0],
          [  0, 255, 255, ...,  0,  0,  0],
          ...,
          [  0,   0,   0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
          [  0,   0,   0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
          [  0,   0,   0, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=np.uint8)

plt.imsave('foo.png', image, cmap="gray")
```

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Is the array syntax wrong?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You are not supposed to copy the `np.array[[ 0, ...` part to your script. That is the output of the `image` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you copied part of the output into your code.

Here is the right code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = (128,128)
image = np.zeros(size).astype(np.uint8)
image[1:64,1:64] = 255

plt.imsave('foo.png', image, cmap="gray")
```